# target_link_libraries in CMAKE using android studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cmake

I am facing a weird issue and it's difficult to know why because the compiler doesnt give any errors.

I created a new project in android studio 2.2.2 with C++ support. 
I edited the .cpp file inside src/main/cpp and compiled the project to obtain (.so) file that i can use as a shared library. To this point everything works perfect.

Here is where the problem occurs:

I am trying to link prebuild shared libraries from ffmpeg. I have already build the libraries in .so format and all I need to do is link them to my .cpp file.

To link the libraries, I opened the CMakeLists.txt inside android studio and told cmake to link those prebuild shared libraries using the following code:

`add_library(libavformat SHARED IMPORTED)`

`set_target_properties(libavformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  C:/Android  /SDK/MyProjects/ffmpeg_to_jpg/P3/app/src/main/jniLibs/libavformat-55.so)`

`include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/)`

`target_link_libraries(native-lib  libavformat)`

This code basically links libavformat to native-lib (which is created from my .cpp file)

The linking process works fine, the reason is because the compiler doesn't cry about any dependencies.

However, my original shared library (native-lib) stops working, and by that I mean, I cannot call any functions from within it.

If i remove the linking line

```
target_link_libraries(native-lib  libavformat)
```

The native-lib.so works fine and I can call any function from within that does not depend on libavformat.

I am not sure what is going on, like I said the compiler doesnt issue any warnings or errors. it is almost like after the linking process the content of native-lib is overwritten by libavformat!!!!

any ideas?

Comment: I have done a lot of googling and still with no success. Basically I recompiled ffmpeg source files into (.so) files that are supported by the armv7-a CPUs which is what my tablet (nexus 7) supports. my only suspension now is that the since the ffmpeg (.so) files were created outside of android cmake , it is casuing some type of failure, especially since my .cpp is compiled into .so format using cmake.

Comment: Is the .so compiled for the correct ABI?